# import mobx-state-tree throws Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mobx

```
import { types } from "mobx-state-tree";
```

Throws an error

```
mobx-state-tree.module.js:2354 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at CoreType.BaseType (mobx-state-tree.module.js:2354)
    at CoreType.SimpleType [as constructor] (mobx-state-tree.module.js:2554)
    at new CoreType (mobx-state-tree.module.js:6418)
    at Module.<anonymous> (mobx-state-tree.module.js:6491)
    at Module../node_modules/mobx-state-tree/dist/mobx-state-tree.module.js (mobx-state-tree.module.js:8319)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../js/app.js (app.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.0 (global.js:20)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
```

Why is that? All I am doing is importing.

The version is 5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I had to update mobx to version 6 from version 5